# BigPictureStyle Notification not showing properly in Xiaomi MIUI-8

Tags: android, android-notifications

I wanted to display a bigPictureStyle Notification in MiUi(don't want to use custom view) using the following code--

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(msg)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
.bigPicture(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.b))
                                        .setBigContentTitle(title));
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(10, mBuilder.build());
```

It works perfectly on raw android but in **Xiaomi MIUI 8** (Android Lollipop based) it shows a shadow at the bottom of expanded notification view as in the picture--

[image: MIUI8 expanded notification having black shadow at the bottom]

How to **remove this bottom shadow**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution for now is using a custom view with similar looking big content view.